# Referencing Bindings in Connections Inspector

Tags: xcode, cocoa, cocoa-bindings, connection, inspector

I'm new to Xcode 4.2, and I have a sample code from Apple, and I'm playing with it to make myself familiar with Xcode.

I made a similar project with that of Apple's, and one button of my project (in Connections Inspector), has less options in comparison with Apple's, which has two more options, "Bindings" and "Referencing Bindings".

See screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

My question is how can I add the two more options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe those only appear if you have already connected the item through the bindings tab.

Comment: So they will appear when I made the necessary connections between the button and the other objects? What's the difference between Bindings and Referencing Bindings?

Comment: Referencing Bindings are other objects that are bound to the selected item. Bindings are things that the item is bound to.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same question and posted in the apple developer forums...the additional two inspectors are only available in OS X projects, not in iOS projects...if you open an OS X project in XCODE you will see them

Comment: Would you mind updating your answer to include a link to your question on the Apple developer forums?